# Is it safe StringToHash() to use in Unity?

Tags: unity, scripting

I'm currently browsing through the Unity tutorials and saw that they're recommending to use `Animator.StringToHash("some string")` to created *unique ids* for animation properties ([see here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-scripting)).

Since I'm a programmer, to me the word "hash" doesn't represents something unique. Like the Java documentation for [hashValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) states:

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal [...], then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

So, according to this (and my definition of "hash"), *two strings may have the same hash value*. (You can also argue that there are an infinite number of possible strings but only 2^32 possible `int` values.)

**So, is there a possibility that `StringToHash()` will give me an id that actually belongs to another property (than the one I requested the hash for)?**

Comment: From what I understood, the Get/Set Animator. functions are also calling this function (hash), that's why they recommend to use the hash directly, so you do not compute the hash every call/frame, as in when you call .SetFloat("param", 1f), the SetFloat function will first call StringToHash("param") then set the value of the param. So even if the collisions will exists, you cannot avoid them by not using this function directly.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the hash function used by StringToHash doesn't have serious bias, the chance of two hashes being alike is one in 4 billion. When you generate a lot of hashes, the chance of a collision gets larger than one would expect (see [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)), but when you have 100 different strings, the overall chance of a collision is still at about a million to one.

I assume that you will have less than 100 animation properties. I would also assume that your names are constants and that you have control over the names you choose, so in the unlikely chance that you do get a collision, you could easily change one of the involved names.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, but man, that's super weird.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are possible [collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) for every hashing algorithm when the amount of information of the hash value is less than the input value. That's a general unavoidable problem.

Depending on the case but generally hashing algorithm are designed to minimize the probability of a collision. 
I don't know which algorithm Unity3D uses to implement that method, but the collision is very unlikely to happen.

If you have the suspect you have a collision check your hash values (and eventually signal the problem to Unity staff since the algorithm should be robust enough to avoid it, and Mecanim should have internal mechanism to detect that 2 parameters have colliding hashes).